# Splitting dataframe gives strange output

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split

I'm simply trying to split my dataframe into several dataframes based on the value of my column `intervention`, but I'm getting some unexpected output when I try and do this.

Checking I do indeed have a dataframe named `raw`:

```
print(class(raw));
```

yields

```
[1] "data.frame"
```

Here's the dataframe before the split:

```
  position                                   id equation      intervention
1       -2 D9E4262D-5B6D-ADB8-D605-B97D63437064      9,5            corral
2        1 B2FFB0B0-210E-022F-293A-0ABFDDB3DC4B      2,3            corral
3        1 85905A69-50F7-AF73-7A51-08B8FDCFAF2D      1,2         horseshoe
4       -2 76A55530-5A39-6A73-3216-D276EABFA2F6      3,4 test_intervention
5       -1 4CFA5D1B-EA32-8584-A1C9-540D9FFB24CB      3,4 test_intervention
```

Then I use

```
groups <- split(raw, raw$intervention);
```

and when I print

```
print(groups);
```

I get this:

```
$corral.corral.horseshoe.test_intervention.test_intervention
  position                                   id equation      intervention
1       -2 D9E4262D-5B6D-ADB8-D605-B97D63437064      9,5            corral
2        1 B2FFB0B0-210E-022F-293A-0ABFDDB3DC4B      2,3            corral
3        1 85905A69-50F7-AF73-7A51-08B8FDCFAF2D      1,2         horseshoe
4       -2 76A55530-5A39-6A73-3216-D276EABFA2F6      3,4 test_intervention
5       -1 4CFA5D1B-EA32-8584-A1C9-540D9FFB24CB      3,4 test_intervention
```

Which doesn't look like a list of dataframes grouped by intervention. Also notice the strange line

```
$corral.corral.horseshoe.test_intervention.test_intervention
```

**EDIT**

Output of dput(raw):

```
structure(list(position = list(-2, 1, 1, -2, -1), id = list("D9E4262D-5B6D-ADB8-D605-B97D63437064",
    "B2FFB0B0-210E-022F-293A-0ABFDDB3DC4B", "85905A69-50F7-AF73-7A51-08B8FDCFAF2D",
    "76A55530-5A39-6A73-3216-D276EABFA2F6", "4CFA5D1B-EA32-8584-A1C9-540D9FFB24CB"),
    equation = list("9,5", "2,3", "1,2", "3,4", "3,4"), intervention = list(
        "corral", "corral", "horseshoe", "test_intervention",
        "test_intervention")), .Names = c("position", "id", "equation",
"intervention"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT** 
Here's my full code, it's small.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript --slave
require("rjson", quietly=TRUE);

# First we need to grab the items from the R api, and save them into a data frame
raw = fromJSON(file="http://some/url.com");

#reformats data into dataframe
raw <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,raw));
#we need to create a new dataframe formatted according to the needs of catR
groups <- split(raw, raw$intervention);
print(groups); 
#saveRDS(object=fromJSON(file="http://some/url.com"),file="/home/bitnami/IRT_data/core_standard.rda");
```

I run my code like so:

```
~/Rscript my_R_file.R
```

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Please provide the output from `dput(raw)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
raw1<-read.table(header=T,text="  position                                   id equation      intervention
1       -2 D9E4262D-5B6D-ADB8-D605-B97D63437064      9,5            corral
2        1 B2FFB0B0-210E-022F-293A-0ABFDDB3DC4B      2,3            corral
3        1 85905A69-50F7-AF73-7A51-08B8FDCFAF2D      1,2         horseshoe
4       -2 76A55530-5A39-6A73-3216-D276EABFA2F6      3,4 test_intervention
5       -1 4CFA5D1B-EA32-8584-A1C9-540D9FFB24CB      3,4 test_intervention")

groups <- split(raw1, raw1$intervention)

> groups
$corral
  position                                   id equation intervention
1       -2 D9E4262D-5B6D-ADB8-D605-B97D63437064      9,5       corral
2        1 B2FFB0B0-210E-022F-293A-0ABFDDB3DC4B      2,3       corral

$horseshoe
  position                                   id equation intervention
3        1 85905A69-50F7-AF73-7A51-08B8FDCFAF2D      1,2    horseshoe

$test_intervention
  position                                   id equation      intervention
4       -2 76A55530-5A39-6A73-3216-D276EABFA2F6      3,4 test_intervention
5       -1 4CFA5D1B-EA32-8584-A1C9-540D9FFB24CB      3,4 test_intervention
```

not getting same as you. Seems to work fine

raw is your dataframe, raw1 is the read.table version

```
> str(raw1$intervention)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "corral","horseshoe",..: 1 1 2 3 3
> str(raw$intervention)
List of 5
 $ : chr "corral"
 $ : chr "corral"
 $ : chr "horseshoe"
 $ : chr "test_intervention"
 $ : chr "test_intervention"
```

When you convert the output from RJSON to a data.frame it is creating a dataframe of lists

this line is your problem

```
#reformats data into dataframe
raw <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,raw));
```

use

```
 raw2<-data.frame(lapply(raw,unlist))
```

Comment: I also get this when I just copy and paste the text into the terminal as you have done here...

Comment: Oh I see, looking at the dput of raw1. So fromJson gives me a list of dataframes with one variable each. as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,raw) attempts to turn it into a proper dataframe, but now I have a dataframe where each row is a list. Is there a means I could format it into a proper dataframe?

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate `raw <- data.frame(lapply(raw, unlist))` looks like it will get `raw` into a proper data frame from its current state. But there may be a better way that skips this odd state entirely.